# Should I attempt to repair this mouse damaged due to power surge?

Tags: power, usb-device, surge-protection

I have a mouse that no longer works after I unplugged and replugged in my computer at the mains (something I rarely do).

My only guess is that the mouse is designed badly and experienced some form of power surge. When I plug it in, I get a momentary flash of light from it's LED (which is meant to remain constant), though it is recognized as a mouse via the computer, however **no** function on the mouse works.

Could this be due to a passive component or voltage regulator being damaged? If so I may be able to repair it, though if it is a programmed chip that's damaged I realize I have no chance of repair.

This is (was) my only working good mouse and I can't get it replaced til next week, hence I'm willing to take a risk here. The mouse is a zowie EC2A.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Take a risk? What risk? It is already broken. Feel free to break it further.

Comment: @EugeneSh. If I wait I may be able to get is replaced by the manufacturer, though I wanted to inquire whether it would be worth the risk.

Comment: In the situation described, suspicion should fall on the computer (or possibly mains wiring), not the mouse.  Unless the mouse is special, it's cheaper to replace than worry about, but you may still have a real problem elsewhere.

Comment: If you can to get a replacement - get it. Don't void the warranty. Go to a closest dollar store and get a cheap mouse to work with until then.

Comment: are you sure it wasn't a coincidental frayed wire , more often the cause of USB types. Or was it an old PS2-

Comment: My first suggestion is to check to make sure youre not using a Windows OS.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 It's a Zowie EC2-A Wired USB Optical Gaming Mouse

Answer (score 1):

You can open the mouse to see what is inside. The first suspect would be the cable, but you say that mouse is being detected, if it is USB mouse, then cable should not be the issue.

Thus I am afraid you are right in that something got damaged in the mouse in terms of logic. The only other serviceable part is button, but in clearly not the suspect in your circumstances.

> If I wait I may be able to get is replaced by the manufacturer

If you will try repairing it yourself it may be visible and manufacturer may refuse to replace the device. Beware!